# C# dgv open new form on pressing enter

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a search bar, from which the results are posted in a dgv. When i double click the cell content, a new form is opened.

```
 private void dgv_Result_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        sc.Open();
        string sqlQueryStr = "SELECT Main_ID FROM dbo.Main WHERE Main_Subject = @Get_Current_Subject";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQueryStr, sc);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Get_Current_Subject", dgv_Result.CurrentCell.Value.ToString());
        int Selected_Subject_ID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        sc.Close();

        Show_Resource Show_This = new Show_Resource(Selected_Subject_ID);
        Show_This.ShowDialog();



        //MessageBox.Show(dgv_Result.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
    }
```

This is working fine using this code.

Is there anyway that i can re-use this code on pressing enter, like a perform_doubleclick() on the cell function ?

```
private void dgv_Result_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
       Perform working code
    }
}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not using the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` you could just create a method that gets called by both events